# AngularJS service gets the data, but doesn`t return it to the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

scope.membersWarnings in controller is always empty, but in service it gets the data from the server. Somehow my data from the server is lost between callback of get function in service and controller.

Controller:

```
AndreaApp.controller('MemberDetailController', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$http','$location','$routeParams','MemberService','MemberGroupsService','ArrivalsService','WarningsService','NotificationsService',function (scope,rootScope, http,location,routeParams,MemberService,MemberGroupsService,ArrivalsService,WarningsService,NotificationsService) { 

scope.member = MemberService.get(routeParams.id);
scope.membersGroup = MemberService.membersGroup(routeParams.id);
scope.membersWarnings = WarningsService.get(routeParams.id);

scope.editMember = function(id){
    location.path('/editMember/'+id);
}

scope.membersDocument = function(id){
    location.path('/membersDocument/'+id);
}

scope.templates =
[ { name: 'packages.html', url: 'views/members/packages.html'},
{ name: 'notifications.html', url: 'views/members/notifications.html'},
{ name: 'warnings.html', url: 'views/members/warnings.html'},
{ name: 'arrivals.html', url: 'views/members/arrivals.html'} ];

scope.template = scope.templates[0];
scope.loadTemplate = function(templateId){
    if(templateId == 3){
        scope.arrivals = ArrivalsService.get(routeParams.id).arrivalsId;
        console.log(scope.arrivals);
    }
    scope.template = scope.templates[templateId];
}}]);
```

WarningsService:

```
AndreaApp.service('WarningsService', function ($http,$q) {
var warnings = [];
this.save = function (warnings, memberId) {

  $http.post('/api/warnings/new/member/'+memberId, 
  {
    name: warnings.name,
    description: warnings.description,
    readed: false,   
    clanId: memberId
  }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Error occurred while adding a warning. HTTP Respone: " + status);    
  });


}

this.get = function (id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/warnings/member/'+id).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              warnings.length = 0;
              console.log(data);
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                warnings.push(data[i]);

              }
              deferred.resolve(data);

              //data exists here, it is not empty
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              alert("HTTP status:" + status)
            });
    return deferred;
}});
```

Comment: No need to use `$q` when `$http` already returns a promise. You are getting the promise in controller, where do you use that promise to access the data?

Comment: scope.membersWarnings = WarningsService.get(routeParams.id);
And I get nothing. I have tried without $q, i get the same result.
It`s like the return it`s not working. I`m confused :D

Comment: try `WarningsService.get(routeParams.id).then(function(resp){ scope.membersWarnings = resp.data; })`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.
I think that the problem is with asynchronuos calls that angularJS makes.

Comment: just return `$http` from service, don't need `$q`

Comment: TypeError: WarningsService.get(...).then is not a function....

Comment: `.then` is not a function because you are still returning a deferred object. you need to return your `$http` object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope.member = MemberService.get(routeParams.id);
```

Should be

```
MemberService.get(routeParams.id).then(function(data) {
    scope.member = data;
});
```

This is because your get method is returning a promise, so once it is resolved, u can obtain the data.

Also, your get method needs to be changed to

```
return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just return the $http, like this:

```
this.get = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/api/warnings/member/'+id);
}
```

Then you could use it on the Controller.

```
WarningsService.get(routeParams.id).then(function(result){
    $scope.membersWarnings = result.data; // or just result
});
```

You cant just assign like you're doing, because you're returning a promise this way. The result isnt ready yet at that moment